# Drag and drop to a child iframe using react-dnnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I cannot drop elements onto iframe that is rendering my own components.

I'm trying to implement drag and drop functionality to a child iframe component.
After passing a dropRef, from a pareent, to a component rendering the iframe, dropping works only on components outside the iframe (IFrame is rendering my own components, not a separate website, so there is no CORS policy problem).

However, dropping does not work on the elements inside the iframe, even after passing the dropRef inside.

I checked this, and some other examples, but nothing seems to be working (Examples below seem to show wrong information in the alert).

https://codesandbox.io/examples/package/react-dnd-multi-iframe-backend

Is there any simple way to drop the draggable elements into the iframe?